# Getting a specific occurrence of items in a List

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, generic-collections

I want to get a specific occurrance of a collection with all the items in that collection, for instance, **getting all the values in the first occurrence of lets's say 3 occurrences**.

How would I accomplish this if I have the below code? If i is equal to 1, **I just want the first occurrence out of the collection to pass to my ProcessForm4PDFFormFields method with just this one occurrence instead of the entire collection.**

So, the parameter "myResult" would only contain just one of the occurrences to pass based on what "i" is.

```
public void GetForm4Results(string FormId, int LoanId, string MainDir3, string TemplateFile, Int16 i)
    {
        try
        {
            using (VisionEntities DbContext = new VisionEntities())
            {
                DbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
                DbContext.Database.Connection.Open();

                int? LoanIdTmp = LoanId;

                ObjectResult<SelectForm4_Result> result = DbContext.SelectForm4(8900, LoanId);

                List<SelectForm4_Result> myResult = new List<SelectForm4_Result>();

                myResult = result.ToList();

                ProcessForm4PDFFormFields(myResult, FormId, MainDir3, TemplateFile, i);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Never write `throw ex;`.

Comment: is there some reason other than it doesn't do anything?

Comment: @AaronAnodide: It destroys the stack trace.  If you need to do something in the catch, write `throw;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're saying you want myResult to contain the first `i` objects in result?

```
myResult = result.Take(i).ToList();
```

Or if you want myResult to contain only the `i`th object in result, it would be...

```
myResult = new List<SelectForm4_Result>() { result.ElementAt(i) };
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb739113.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not understanding the question, but if you just want the first item in the list, you could simply do

```
myResult = result.ToList()[0];
```

or if the list contains a lot of different things

```
foreach (object o in result.ToList())
        {
            if (o.Equals(target))
            {
                myResult = o;
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I would not agree to use of "myResult = result.ToList()[0];" if the list is empty then you run into problem plus using "0" index is more static. You can have better option to use "myresult = result.ToList().First()" or "myresult = result.ToList().FirstOrDefault()" and check if myresult is null or not. One is pre check and one is post check.

Comment: When I try and apply the first option, I am getting the msg: Cannot implicitly convert type "PDFConverterModel.SelectForm4_Result" to "Systems.Collections.Generic.List<PDFConverterModel.SelectForm4_Result>". What would the syntax be in the method to peroperly get just this first item?

Comment: Try this 
                ProcessForm4PDFFormFields(new List<PDFConverterModel.SelectForm4_Result>(myResult), FormId, MainDir3, TemplateFile, i);

Comment: But how do I pass only the first occurrence of "myResult" in that first parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
myResult = i == 1 ? new List<PDFConverterModel.SelectForm4_Result>(result.Take(i)) : result.Take(i);

ProcessForm4PDFFormFields(myResult, FormId, MainDir3, TemplateFile, i);
```

Comment: I get the same err msg as before: Cannot implicitly convert type "PDFConverterModel.SelectForm4_Result" to "Systems.Collections.Generic.List<PDFConverterModel.SelectForm4_Result>".

Comment: In additon, I need to be able to pass not only the first occurrance in the List, but any occurrance of what the value of "i" is coming into the method.